# How to make test requests to a web-service with soap envelope?

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client

Is there a online tool that given a specific soap envelope can make the web-service call?

I searched online and i found for rest web-services postman plugin, but for soap the only thing i found and is no longer available is the Poster plugin.

Does anyone know about a simple online tool that can send a soap envelope to a certain web-service?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are. Some of them:

http://www.service-repository.com/client/start

http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html